How to update "Security update" for a Android Studio device (emulator)
I check settings/system/software update/ in Android 14 that is runing in Android Studio. But it always show the device is update to date. And the last security update is September 5, 2023.
Do you know how to get the newest update for the emulator device?
enter image description here
I've installed last update for the SDK Platform - Andriod 14.

The emulator is bound to a specific SDK version. To upgrade, create a new emulator with the desired API level.

I‘ve been upgrade to last version of Andriod 14 SDK. But the last security update still is September 5, 2023 in the new emulator.
